# jQuery password validation strength meter bar

Tags: jquery

I am working on an application that needs to be more visual - what would be the best way of adding a visual bar that mirrors the states of the password strength.

Should I create a score that increments, decrements on the various validations in the keyup - css animates/color changes?

http://jsfiddle.net/by429n9a/53/

```
  $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
    // keyup code here
    // set password variable
    var pswd = $(this).val();
    //validate the length
    if (pswd.length < 8) {
      $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
      $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }

    //validate lowercase
    if (pswd.match(/[a-z]/)) {
      $('#lowercase').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
      $('#lowercase').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }

    //validate capital letter
    if (pswd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
      $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
      $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }

    //validate number
    if (pswd.match(/\d/)) {
      $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
      $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }


  }).focus(function() {
    //$('#pswd_info').show();
  }).blur(function() {
    //$('#pswd_info').hide();
  });

});
```

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/ you might bebetter of asking this question there

Comment: Be sure to read [their help center](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help) to make sure though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/by429n9a/89/